# There is an TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (6 given) when inserting into mysql table

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have made a webscraper in python and I am now trying to get it to output the data i have scraped into a mysqldb but I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it.this is the error I get

```
 File "C:/Users/owner/Downloads/Scrape (2).py", line 16, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO london10dayforecast (Day,Condition,High,Low,) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", str(var1),str(var2),str(var3),str(var4))
TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (6 given)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import MySQLdb

r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/be6eb0a1b404829b/forecast10day/q/UK/London.json")
data = r.json()

for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
var1= day['date']['weekday'] + ":"
var2= "Conditions: ", day['conditions']
var3= "High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "'C"
var4= "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "'C", '\n'

db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","weathersystem" )
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO london10dayforecast (Day,Condition,High,Low,) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", str(var1),str(var2),str(var3),str(var4))
db.commit()
db.close()

``
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the values in as a tuple

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO london10dayforecast (Day,Condition,High,Low) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (str(var1),str(var2),str(var3),str(var4)))
```

or more readably

```
qstr = "INSERT INTO london10dayforecast (Day,Condition,High,Low) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
params = str(var1), str(var2), str(var3), str(var4)
cursor.execute(qstr, params)
```

Comment: Is it still the same error as in question? If not what is new error?

Comment: i noticed, even with the correction i still get this error     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/owner/Downloads/Scrape (2).py", line 17, in <module>
    cursor.execute(qstr, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @RitchieRamnial, use `%s` instead of `?` in the query string

Comment: There is an extra comma next to Low. That might cause a problem. Not sure for MySQLdb but I'm sure it causes a problem in sqlite3.

Comment: @RitchieRamnial, still the `TypeError: not all arguments converted...`?

Comment: im getting this error query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: but i have this code. sql = """INSERT INTO LONDON(DAY, \
       COND, HIGH, LOW) \
       VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%d', '%d')"""
results = str(var1), str(var2), int(var3), int(var4)
cursor.execute(sql, results)
db.commit()