# TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (11 given)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to create a SignUp page using Tornado, Anaconda, MySQLdb connector.
So I have 8 fields in the form and my Signuphandler has the logic to insert the person's input into mysql database.

I searched and followed the documentation and other resources online and -
I tried the following

Initially I was getting this error  **query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**  for 1) and 2)

1)

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_table (firstName, lastName, a, b, c, d, e, f, g) VALUES (%s, %s,    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(firstname, lastname, a, b, c, d, e, f, g,))
```

2)

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_table (firstName, lastName, a, b, c, d, e, f, g) VALUES (%s, %s,    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [(firstname, lastname, a, b, c, d, e, f, g,)])
```

So I googled and removed (), Now I am getting **TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (11 given)** error

3)

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_table (firstName, lastName, a, b, c, d, e, f, g) VALUES (%s, %s,    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", firstname, lastname, a, b, c, d, e, f, g,)
```

4)Followed this [python 3 arguments 6 given error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518498/python-3-arguments-6-given-error)

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_table (firstName, lastName, a, b, c, d, e, f, g) VALUES (%s, %s,     %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", str(firstname), str(lastname), str(a), str(b), str(c), str(d), str(e), str(f), str(g),)
```

What is going wrong here? Can someone pls help me..

Thanks..

Comment: did you try with cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_table (firstName, lastName, a, b, c, d, e, f, g) VALUES (%s, %s,    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % (firstname, lastname, a, b, c, d, e, f, g,))

Comment: why not simply google the proper usage of `cursor.execute()`?

Comment: @user3 You do not use the normal string formatting on SQL! Never! You will get vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cursor.execute(
    """INSERT INTO user_table
        (firstName, lastName,
         a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
        VALUES
        (%s, %s,
         %s, %s, %s, %s,
         %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
    (firstname, lastname,
     a, b, c, d,
     e, f, g,))
```

If I count well you have 10 times '%s' and 9 arguments for them. Try to remove one '%s'

Comment: Thank you @Andrei Boyanov.. The error disappeared, but the database is not updated..Let me check on that.. Thanks again!!